# Backend instance at custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine

I was unable to access my Backend Instance at custom domain.

For example, I have an app and I access the Normal Instance sucessfully at:

http://www.[my_app_id].appspot.com **or** http://[my_app_id].appspot.com

And I have a backend config name=test and I accessed Backend Instance successfully at:

http://test.[my_app_id].appspot.com

In admin interface, the "Instances" link show the instances of Backend and Normal Instance separately. The content show is the same, but is easy to see when a request go to the Backend Instance and when go to Normal Instance.

---

Then I configured the wildcard "test" in Google Apps to access my Backend Instance at a custom URL:

I continue access the Normal Instance sucessfully at:

http://www.[my_domain].com **or** http://[my_domain].com

But request at

http://test.[my_domain].com

redicted to the Normal Instance instead of Backend Instance.

The doc's said it should work but I cann't at this moment and I need uses custom domain because my app is multitenancy.

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your backed is really supposed to be accessed by the front end, as I understand it.

So when your application front end makes a request to it's back end (e.g. via a URL), it'll work as it's all done internally.

Have you set your back end to be publicly accessible?

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview#Public_and_Private_Backends

> Backends are private by default, since they typically function as a component inside an application, rather than acting as its public face. Private backends can be accessed by application administrators, instances of the application, and by App Engine APIs and services (such as Task Queue tasks and Cron jobs) without any special configuration. Backends are not primarily intended for user-facing traffic, but you can make a backend public for testing or for interacting with an external system.

I don't know why the redirection is not working, but perhaps you should modify your question to show what problem it is you are trying to solve here and get an answer to that instead?

Comment: In admin interface, the "Instances" link show the instances of backend and frontend separately. It's easy to see when a request go to backend and when go to frontend.
The backend config is public because the request at http://test.[my_app_id].appspot.com works fine.
The request at http://test.[my_domain].com access frontend instance =/
The doc's said it should work but I cann't at this moment and I need uses custom domain because my app is multitenancy!

Comment: when you say "The request at test.[my_domain].com access frontend instance =/" I think you may be mistaken. If you go to the "backend" using the same URL scheme as the frontend, then the backend will simply serve up the same content as the frontend. So if you can get a request at all to "test.[my_domain].com" then it must be the backend that is serving that request, even it if "seems" to serve up the same content as the front end is doing (in effect you have two versions of the app running). The question is, what happens when you go to a handler that the backend is supposed to serve?

Comment: Oh yes, the content is the same, I know that. The difference is only the more CPU/Memory and requests to backends can run indefinitely. When I say "Frontend Instance" in fact I meant to say "Normal Instance"

I will update my question again

Comment: perhaps you should post the DNS/name records you have used to do the domain configuration? If you are getting to app.com instead of x.app.com when you go to x.app.com then it's gotta be related to mappings you've used (I'd guess!)